# types stored in sockadrr_in structure not recognized

Tags: c, sockets, types

I am relatively new in C programming, and especially in socket programming, but I have spent much time trying to help myself on this question and haven't found anything, I hope somebody will be able to help. So here is the problem (I write only the line where I have the problem)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
typedef int SOCKET;

static const int SOCKET_ERROR = -1;

/*Variables initialisation*/
int32_t filtersize1=0;
int32_t filtersize2=0;
SOCKET sock;
unsigned int bytes_sent = 0;
int success = TRUE;
int erreur2=0;
int erreur3=0;


static char const *DEF_HOST_IP = "132.166.142.227"/* default target host address*/
static const unsigned short DEF_HOST_PORT = 15000;          /* default target port */
struct sockaddr_in hostinfo;

/* Store TCP/IP parameters */
hostinfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
hostinfo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( *DEF_HOST_IP);
hostinfo.sin_port = htons( DEF_HOST_PORT);
```

When I compile I get the error " expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '.' token", and that on the line where I fill the sockadrr_in structure (named hostinfo) My guess would be that the code doesn't recognize the sockadrr_in as a structure type, or doesn't recognize the type stored in this structure, but I already used this code on another machine and it was working. I precise I already tried setting the structure to zero before and I have the same problem. If anybody had a solution this would really help me because I don't know what to try anymore. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that code in a function body (such as `main()`) or outside? if outside, it's not valid..

Comment: Do not add things like "solved" to the title, but select an answer as the accepted one. If none fits, write your own answer and accept this. Therefore I rolled back your last edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize structs in the following fashion:

```
// compiles
struct sockaddr_in hostinfo = {
     .sin_family = AF_INET
};
```

But as soon as you add a function call, it will no longer work because the elements are no longer constant. To the compiler, adding this function call means that the element is not constant, so it doesn't know what to store for the global object.

```
// does not compile
struct sockaddr_in hostinfo = {
     .sin_family = AF_INET,
     .sin_port = htons(DEF_HOST_PORT),
};
```

Also, you have a missing semicolon in the line:

```
static char const *DEF_HOST_IP = "132.166.142.227"
```

Going off of what @klas-lindback said, you should be initializing `hostinfo` as part of a function somewhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

static char const *DEF_HOST_IP = "132.166.142.227"; /* default target host address*/
static const unsigned short DEF_HOST_PORT = 15000;  /* default target port */
struct sockaddr_in hostinfo;

void setup_hostinfo()
{
    /* Store TCP/IP parameters */
    hostinfo.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    hostinfo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(DEF_HOST_IP);
    hostinfo.sin_port        = htons(DEF_HOST_PORT);
}

int main(void) {

    /* setup our hostinfo */
    setup_hostinfo();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only declarations are allowed outside a function body.

The lines:

```
/* Store TCP/IP parameters */
hostinfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
hostinfo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( *DEF_HOST_IP);
hostinfo.sin_port = htons( DEF_HOST_PORT);
```

are not declarations and must be put inside a function.

Comment: This is probably it. Another issue is calling `inet_addr(*DEF_HOST_IP);` when you need to be calling it like `inet_addr(DEF_HOST_IP);`.

Comment: Ok this is exactly the problem, it was outside of my function. Thank you very much for the help my problem is solved.